# How to duplicate page in a DOCX file with python

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I am using `python-docx-template` and `python-docx` to create DOCX file with one page. I need to duplicate the page in the document nth times. How can I do this with python?

Answer (score 0):

`python-docx` doesn't have pages. However, it recognizes sections, so before you load the document with `python-docx`, make sure you insert section breaks before and after your target page.

However, currently, `python-docx` doesn't have APIs for grabbing the content of a section. If you really want it, you will have to walk through its underlying XML. You may start looking at it from `document.__body`, by `print(document.__body)`.

You are basically looking for the contents between `w:sectPr`. See its documentation here:

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/sections.html